# Mysql Stored procedure for a Fixture

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064, fixture

i cannot finish this becaus is giving me an annoying error that i check and check but i still don't know what is going on, here is the code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS gen_par;

CREATE PROCEDURE gen_par()
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpPool;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpFixture;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpPool (
        J           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ID          INT NOT NULL,
        unpicked    BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
        , PRIMARY KEY ( J )
    );
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpFixture (
        ID          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        HomeID      INT NOT NULL,
        AwayID      INT NOT NULL,
        GrpNum      INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
    );

    INSERT INTO tmpPool (ID)
    SELECT      id
    FROM        equipos
    ORDER BY    id;

    SELECT  COUNT(*)  INTO  @NumTeams  FROM tmpPool;
    IF @NumTeams % 2    THEN
        INSERT INTO tmpPool (ID) VALUES (0);
        SET @NumTeams       = @NumTeams + 1;
    END IF;

    ALTER TABLE  tmpPool  CHANGE COLUMN J  J  INT      NOT NULL
    , ADD INDEX  J_foo  (J ASC)
    , DROP PRIMARY KEY;

    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES    = 0;   -- Kill bogus warnings on updates.

    SET     @GroupNum       = 1;
    WHILE   @GroupNum < @NumTeams  DO
        REPEAT
            SELECT  ID INTO @Home FROM tmpPool  WHERE unpicked = 1  ORDER BY J ASC   LIMIT 1;
            SELECT  ID INTO @Away FROM tmpPool  WHERE unpicked = 1  ORDER BY J DESC  LIMIT 1;

            INSERT INTO tmpFixture (HomeID, AwayID, GrpNum)
            VALUES      (@Home, @Away, @GroupNum);

            UPDATE  tmpPool  SET unpicked = 0  WHERE ID = @Home  OR  ID = @Away;

            SELECT  COUNT(*) INTO  @TeamsLeft  FROM tmpPool  WHERE unpicked = 1;

        UNTIL @TeamsLeft < 1
        END REPEAT;

        SET @GroupNum = @GroupNum + 1;
        UPDATE  tmpPool  SET unpicked = 1;

        UPDATE  tmpPool  SET J = J + 1  WHERE J > 1;
        UPDATE  tmpPool  SET J = 2      WHERE J = @NumTeams + 1;
    END WHILE;

    INSERT INTO
        partidos (eqloc, eqvis)
    SELECT
        IF( F.HomeID = 0, (SELECT id FROM equipos eq WHERE eq.id = F.AwayID), (SELECT id FROM equipos eq WHERE eq.id = F.HomeID) ),
        IF( F.AwayID = 0 || F.HomeID = 0, 0, (SELECT id FROM equipos eq WHERE eq.id = F.AwayID) ),
    FROM
        tmpFixture F
        ORDER BY 
                F.GrpNum,
            1;
    END;
```

The error is:

```
 [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
    tmpFixture F
    ORDER BY 
            F.GrpNum,
            1;
  END' at line 65
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just a note, im using navicat, so im ignoring the delimiter stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part:

```
IF( F.AwayID = 0 || F.HomeID = 0, 0, (SELECT id FROM equipos eq WHERE eq.id = F.AwayID) ),
FROM
    tmpFixture F
```

You have a trailing comma at the end of the first line, before the FROM. It shouldn't be there.